# How can I edit specific characters from a string within a separate method?

Tags: java, string, methods

```
public static String replaceExclamation(String userText){
   int i = 0;
   for ( i=0; i < userText.length(); ++i) {
      char currentChar = userText.charAt(i);
      if (currentChar == '!') {
         userText.charAt(i) = ".";
      }
   }
   return userText;
}
```

I am trying to replace all the '!' in a string with a '.' but I am getting an unexpected type error.
What does this mean and how can I fix it?

Also, does the fact that userText is from **main** instead of this local method impact my ability to edit the string?

Comment: `String` instances are immutable. In order to "edit" a `String` you must create a 
new instance—see [`String.replace(char,char)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#replace(char,char)).You're also trying to assign `"."` to a method call, which is not valid.

Comment: In userText.charAt(i) = "." left hand side is a value not a variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`String` is immutable, if you replace any character in `String` then with that change new `String` object is created, so i prefer using `StringBuilder` for this

```
public static StringBuilder replaceExclamation(StringBuilder userText){
  int i = 0;
 for ( i=0; i < userText.length(); ++i) {
  char currentChar = userText.charAt(i);
  if (currentChar == '!') {
     userText.setCharAt(i,'.');
    }
  }
  return userText;
}
```

Or you can use `replace(char oldChar, char newChar)`

```
String result = userText.replace('!', '.');
```

Or you can use `replaceAll(String regex, String replacement)`

```
String result = userText.replaceAll("!", ".");
```